# Could not find trusted certificate

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, certificate-authority

**Problem:**

I'm getting a thrown error from javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException (see attached picture)

[image]

Is it possible for Java to have a corrupt or missing CA cert? If so how can I repair or resolve this issue/error?

**Things I've Tried:**

1. I have removed all versions of JRE from the PC and installed the latest version of JRE (1.6.14).
2. Cleaned and removed all unnecessary Trusted Cert's from the User section of Certificates.
3. Try running keytool to get the fingerprints of the CA's

When trying to run the keytool I'm getting the following:

**keytool error: java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: java.io.IOException: subject key, java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: Unknown key spec.**

Comment: can you supply some details of what url you are attempting to connect to?

Comment: Due to privacy control I cannot release the URL I'm trying to connect to. I've tried connecting on another machine with success. So I know it's an environment issue not a code issue or server side issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is theoretically possible, but IMO highly unlikely, that Java has a corrupt CA cert.  It is more likely that the CA cert you want is not in the JRE's cacerts store.  You can check on the contents of the store (on Linux at least) using 'keytool'; e.g.

```
keytool -list -keystore /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_14/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

Scan through that listing to see if you can see the fingerprint for the CAcert that your URL requires.

Reference: the [JDK 6.0 JDK Development Tools / Security Tools](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/index.html#security) page/section.